# How can I centralize vertically roots in an equation?

Tags: equations, align, vertically

When I execute this code

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\begin{document}    
$\sqrt[n]{a\cdot b}=\sqrt[n]{a}\cdot \sqrt[n]{b}$
\end{document}
```

the individual equations on the right side are not centralized.

[image]

Is there a way to align them vertically?

Thank you!
Igor

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 3):

One option is to add a `\vphantom` for the larger argument in the smaller one:

```
$\sqrt[n]{a\cdot b}=\sqrt[n]{\vphantom{b}a}\cdot \sqrt[n]{b}$
```

[image]